# Spring-social example is not working

Tags: spring-security, spring-social

I am getting the following error while trying to access the spring-social examples. Could somebody please guide me .

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "signin", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolver
```

Comment: There's not enough info here to be sure. The simple answer is what the exception itself says: There's a missing signin.html file. Any help I could give beyond that would require me knowing *which* Spring Social Sample you're trying, whether you cloned it from GitHub or coded it yourself, did you make any tweaks to it after cloning it, etc, etc?

Comment: However, the question was good enough for me to find it here (and its answer!), and good enough for Roy to answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like running "gradlew tomcatRunWar" task instead of the documented "gradlew tomcatRun" task allows it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may import the  project to eclipse and run from eclipse. That will work